# Emacs indent after :config emacs-lisp

Tags: emacs, config, indentation

I have the code block:

```
(use-package dired
  :config
  (setq dired-auto-revert-buffer t))
```

I want this to instead be indented like:

```
(use-package dired
  :config
    (setq dired-auto-revert-buffer t))
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that's not possible. The closest I could get was `(put 'use-package 'lisp-indent-function '2)`, which gave me

```
(use-package dired
    :config
  (setq dired-auto-revert-buffer t))
```

This just makes it indented the same was as

```
(if cond
    a
  b)
```

I don't think there's a way to make it indented like you wanted, since that's not a standard way to indent lisp code.